# Reset Opera titlebar back to hidden

Tags: gui, opera, themes

I'm a massive fan of Opera, but I can't figure how to flip the GUI back to where the main titlebar is hidden again. Any ideas?

[image: Opera GUI]

Back to its original look:

[image: Opera GUI reset]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under *Appearance - Skins*, choose "Opera Standard".

Comment: That's it!  Tried everything, didn't think support for hiding the top bar was dependant on the theme.

Answer (score 2):

Unselect "File|Show Menu Bar". If you don't want to see the tab preview, drag and drop the tab line up:

```
+--------+ +--------+
|        | |        |
|        | |        |
|        | |        |
+        +-----------------
drag this line up  ----^
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll be keeping my tab previews.  Handy for those visual of us!

Answer (score 1):

(I hope I'm understanding your question correctly.)  Press **Shift-F12**, then change the appropriate checkboxes under the "Toolbars" tab to suit your needs:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I can't find the option to reset the Opera title bar, I've added more to my original question to explain more clearly.

Comment: Ah, so it's a Theme issue -- thanks for updating your question, by the way (+1).